# Как сделать автоприцел?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Как сделать автоприцел оружия к ближайшему врагу в 2D?
То есть, в руке персонажа находиться пушка, ей нужно целиться в ближайшего от нее врага(Объекта с тегом Enemy)

Я раньше в 3D с LookAt это делал, но тут какие то проблемы, пушка начинает вращаться по всем осям, а мне нужно, чтобы она вращалась только по Z, дак еще и было бы хорошо скорость поворота пушки учитывать.